# How to fix: Automapper 11 with conflict dependency

Tags: .net, automapper-11

After upgrade of Autommaper from 10 to the latest v.11 and Automapper.Collection to the latest v.7 it appears there is a conflict.

Is it by design? Should I worry that it might cause problems in future? How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those package versions are incompatible. If you need the collections package, you must use AM 10. See
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection/issues/162

**Update**

@jbogard was kind enough to do the port himself :)

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection/pull/164

AutoMapper.Collection 8 works with AM 11.